# Firestore manipulating other users data

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have been exploring Firebase and from my first impressions it looks really good.

I will use Auth for authentication because it's simple and I do not want to write yet another sign in/up system.

I have been looking at firestore for saving data, because it's simple and I do not have to manage a server.

And here comes the problem; Many of the examples I have seen put rules to show only the current rows with "ID" the Auth UID which they pass from the client.

But can the user can decompile my app, change the UID to other user's UID and read/write to their data?

Is this true or am I missing something?

Comment: The way to think about this is that Auth UID is not 'passed from the client'. Assuming the Firebase rules require authentication to read data, once a user authenticates, a variable *Auth* is populated with the uid *from the server*. That enables you, the developer, to access that uid ( as a variable, live in code) to refer to that user elsewhere in your Firebase; storing other information about the user in a /users node for example. Again [Firebase Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/?authuser=0) dictate what can/cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

UIDs are handled by Firebase on the server side. There is no way to reverse engineer an app and change the UID.

If for some reason a user does that or anything similar, he won't be able to login to the app thus won't have access to the data stored on Cloud Firestore.